# Showing a polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

### The Problem

> Let $a_0=1$ and recursively define $a_n$ to be the smallest prime number **strictly greater than** $a_0+...+a_{n-1}$
>   then $(a_n)_{n\geq 0 }$, it follows that $$a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+...+a_n$$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Another way of defining $a_n=\min\{p|p>a_0+...+a_{n-1} \text{ and } p \text{ is prime}\}$

Here is the first couple numbers in the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$: 
$(1,2,5,11,23,43,89,...)$

Here is the first couple of polynomials:

$$1$$

$$x+2$$

$$x^2+2x+5$$

$$x^3+2x^2+5x+11$$

$$x^4+2x^3+5x^2+11x+23$$

$$x^5+2x^4+5x^3+11x^2+23x+43$$

$$x^6+2x^5+5x^4+11x^3+23x^2+43x+89$$

### My Thoughts

It is clear that if we can find some prime $p$ where $q_n(x)=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+...+a_n$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z_p}[x]$ then $q_n(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. With that said I think that I have to prove:

> $q_n(x)=a_0x^n+...+a_n$ is irreducible in $Z_{a_{n-1}}[x]$

but I am kind of stuck here. Any Ideas?

Comment: Note that if you work modulo the prime $a_n$ your polynomial will not be irreducible, as it will have a factor $x$.

Comment: @MarkBennet I know it was just an error I ment to put $a_{n-1}$

Comment: You didn't say what $a_0$ is.

Comment: @D_S ment to say that $a_0=1$

Comment: The condition is  ‘strictly greater than $a_0+\dots+a_{n-1}$’, per chance?

Comment: @Bernard Yes it is.

Comment: Are $\large a_1,a_2,\cdots a_{n-1}$ arbitary or must they be positive ?

Comment: @Peter $a_1=2$, $a_2=5$,... $a_n=\min\{p| p> a_0+...a_{n-1}, \text{ and } p \text{ is prime} \}$

Comment: $q_n(x)=x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_n$ where $a_n$ is prime can have only rational (actually integer) roots $x=\pm 1;\;x=\pm a_n$. We can see that for the conditions on $a_n$ it cannot be $q_n(1)=a_0+a_1+\ldots+a_n=0$ and it cannot be $q_n(-1)=0$ either. $q_n(a_n)$ let me perplexed because you said nothing on the signs of the coefficients. Anyway I feel that $\pm a_n$ cannot be roots, thus the polynomial is irreducible.

Comment: @Raffaele Given that the numbers are prime numbers strictly greater than the sum of the previous coeffients, it would be a given that $a_n\geq 0$ for all $n\geq 0$.

Comment: @Raffaele How did you could you come to the conclusion about the roots only knowing the coeffients were prime?

Comment: With PARI/GP, I checked the poylnomials upto degree $1\ 000$ without finding a counter-example.

Comment: @user160110 $x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_{n-1}x=-a_n$ collect $x$ in LHS $x\left(x^{n-1}+a_1x^{n-2}+\ldots+a_{n-1}\right)=-a_n$ as we are looking for integer solutions candidate root $x$ must be a divisor of $a_n$,. As $a_n$ is prime, the only possibilities are $\pm 1$ or $\pm a_n$

Comment: @Raffaele A polynomial $p(x)$ can be factorable in $Q[x]$ and have  no rational roots take for example $x^4-5x^2+6=(x^2-2)(x^2-3)$.

Comment: *Here is a thought:* Set $s_n(x)=x^nq_n(\frac{1}{x})$. Then $s_n$ is irreducible iff $q_n$ is. Also $s_n=a_nx^n + s_{n-1}$. I was thinking about "using induction on $n$" (in this case we have a "natural choice" (!) of prime for "reduction modulo prime"), but can't get anything out of it. May be you can find something worth via this.

Comment: @Krish I was thinking something similar except I had $q_n(x)=q_{n-1}(x)x+a_n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Gauss' lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)) states that if a polynomial is irreducible over integers, it is also irreducible over rationals. Let's show the polynomial 
$$P_n(x)=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n−1}+...+a_n$$
such that $$a_n > a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+...+a_0 \tag{1}$$ 
$a_k \in \mathbb{N}^{*},\forall k$ and $a_n$-prime is irreducible over integers.

---

**Proposition 1** If $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ is a root of $P_n(x)$, i.e. $P_n(\alpha)=0$, then $|\alpha|>1$.

Let's suppose $|\alpha| \leq 1$ then 
$$a_0\alpha^n+a_1\alpha^{n−1}+...+a_n=0 \Rightarrow |a_n|=|a_0\alpha^n+a_1\alpha^{n−1}+...+a_{n-1}\alpha| \Rightarrow \\
a_n\leq a_0|\alpha^n|+a_1|\alpha^{n−1}|+...+a_{n-1}|\alpha| \leq a_0+a_1+...+a_{n-1}$$
which contradicts $(1)$

---

**Proposition 2** $P_n(x)$ is irreducible over integers.

Let's suppose it's reducible, i.e. $P_n(x)=G(x)\cdot F(x)$, where $G, F$ are non-constant polynomials with integer coefficients. Then $P_n(0)=G(0)\cdot F(0)=a_n$ which is prime. This means that the absolute values of the last coefficient of $G$ is 1 and of the last coefficient of $F$ is $a_n$ (or vice-versa, but WLOG let's assume so). Let's notes
$$G(x)=b_kx^k+...+b_0, b_i\in \mathbb{Z}, b_k \ne 0, |b_0|=1$$

From [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) we have that the absolute value of the product of $G(x)$'s roots ($G(\gamma_i)=0, \gamma_i \in \mathbb{C}$) is 
$$\left|\prod_{i} \gamma_i \right|= \left|\frac{b_0}{b_k}\right|\leq 1$$

But every single root of $G(x)$ is also a root for $P_n(x)$ and, according to **Proposition 1**, we must have
$$\left|\prod_{i} \gamma_i \right|=\prod_{i} \left|\gamma_i \right|>1$$
So we have a contradiction.

---

[Here](http://yufeizhao.com/olympiad/intpoly.pdf) is a recommended source of inspiration.